# How to fix "unhandled promise rejection error" in try/catch error handling

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make use of the slack devkit located here (https://slack.dev/node-slack-sdk/webhook) to send strings to different slack channels. I'm just trying to include try/catch error handling to post to a static channel if the variable webhook fails.

I've tried all different variations of try/catch but I can't get any of the catch code to work properly. The try logic works fine and as expected. I am new to javascript/nodejs so it's probably a dumb error on my part. I've defined both SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL and SLACK_MONITORING_URL outside of this snippet

```
const TOTAL_GHE_ISSUES = "10" //pulled from DB
const GHE_ISSUE_NUMBERS = "90" //pulled from DB

const IncomingWebhook = require('@slack/webhook').IncomingWebhook; //function grabbed from slack webhook devkit library
var url = SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL //can change this to however we want to grab team's webhook
var webhook = new IncomingWebhook(url)

//timer
// Send the notification, if no webhook is present in owners table, skips

if (url != ""){

    if (TOTAL_GHE_ISSUES != "0"){
        try {
        webhook.send({
            text: "*Daily Overdue Nessus Vulnerability Alert*",
            attachments: [{color: "#FF0000", blocks: [{type: "section",text: {type: "mrkdwn",text: "@here *" + TOTAL_GHE_ISSUES + "* Overdue Nessus Vulnerability issues reported \nOverdue Nessus Vulnerability GHE Issue Numbers: *" + GHE_ISSUE_NUMBERS + "*"}}]}]
          })
        }
        catch(err){
            console.log("Webhook Verification Failed")
            //url = SLACK_MONITORING_URL;
            //webhook = new IncomingWebhook(url)
            //webhook.send({
                //text: "*Nessus Webhook Verification, please investigate broken webhooks:*",
                //attachments: [{color: "#FF0000", blocks: [{type: "section",text: {type: "mrkdwn",text: SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL}}]}]
            //})
        }
    }

    else {
        try {
        webhook.send({
            text: "*Daily Overdue Nessus Vulnerability Alert*",
            attachments: [{color: "#36a64f", blocks: [{type: "section",text: {type: "mrkdwn",text: "@here *NO* Overdue Nessus Vulnerabilities reported"}}]}]
          })
      }
        catch(err){
            //url = SLACK_MONITORING_URL
            //webhook = new IncomingWebhook(url)
            //webhook.send({
                //text: "*Nessus Webhook Verification, please investigate broken webhooks:*",
                //attachments: [{color: "#FF0000", blocks: [{type: "section",text: {type: "mrkdwn",text: SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL}}]}]
            //})
        }
  }     
}

else {
  console.log("No webhook provided")}
```

I would expect the first catch(err) to post to console.log (and eventually add more functionality but I just want this basic test case) but instead I get this error

```
    at Object.requestErrorWithOriginal (/Users/BrandonKonieczny/Documents/GitHub/node-slack-sdk/node_modules/@slack/webhook/dist/errors.js:25:33)
    at IncomingWebhook.send (/Users/BrandonKonieczny/Documents/GitHub/node-slack-sdk/node_modules/@slack/webhook/dist/IncomingWebhook.js:54:32)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)
(node:65139) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:65139) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the try clause, the *webhook.send* returns a promise, not an error.
What returns an error is the result of the promise itself, so it won't be catched in the catch statement.

In order to cacth it you could make an async/await function and do...

```js
async () => {
try {
        await webhook.send({
            text: "*Daily Overdue Nessus Vulnerability Alert*",
            attachments: [{color: "#FF0000", blocks: [{type: "section",text: {type: "mrkdwn",text: "@here *" + TOTAL_GHE_ISSUES + "* Overdue Nessus Vulnerability issues reported \nOverdue Nessus Vulnerability GHE Issue Numbers: *" + GHE_ISSUE_NUMBERS + "*"}}]}]
          })
        }
        catch(err){
            console.log("Webhook Verification Failed")
            //url = SLACK_MONITORING_URL;
            //webhook = new IncomingWebhook(url)
            //webhook.send({
                //text: "*Nessus Webhook Verification, please investigate broken webhooks:*",
                //attachments: [{color: "#FF0000", blocks: [{type: "section",text: {type: "mrkdwn",text: SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL}}]}]
            //})
        }
}
```

Comment: I've tried integrating the above code as is and I'm getting no apparent result back, whether the try case or the catch case succeeds. It's no longer posting to the slack channel or giving me anything back on the command line when it fails

Comment: The code there represaents a function (you must run it) so, you could declare a constant const a = async ()....

and then doing 
a()

Comment: I've got it working now with that, thank you for the help and your patience!